# Simple JSON Data not being displayed in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wcf, jqgrid

I'm Novice to Jquery and Json. I Have RESTful Webservice written in WCF which returns JSON object. I tried binding this to jqGrid but met with no luck. To test if the problem is with WCF, I saved the JSON object as static file and tried to bind the same to grid just to realise that it's not issue with RESTful service. Finally decided to seek the expert's help. Below is my web page code as is:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <title>My First Grid</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <table id="list"></table>
  <div id="pager"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: 'data.json',
        //url: 'http://localhost/api/ClientData',
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "GET",
        colNames: ["Id#", "Client Name", "Is Active"],
        colModel: [{
          name: "Id",
          sortable: true
        }, {
          name: "Name",
          sortable: true
        }, {
          name: "Active",
          align: "right",
          sortable: false
        }],
        pager: "#pager",
        rowNum: 5,
        rownumbers: true,
        rowList: [5, 10, 15],
        height: 'auto',
        width: '500',
        loadonce: true,
        caption: "Client Data"
      }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
        edit: true,
        add: true,
        del: true,
        search: true
      });
    });
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Here is my 'data.json':

```html
[ { "Id": "1", "Name": "Client 1", "Active":true }, { "Id": "3", "Name": "Client 3", "Active":true }, { "Id": "2", "Name": "Client 2", "Active":false }, { "Id": "5", "Name": "Client 5", "Active":false }, { "Id": "4", "Name": "Client 4", "Active":true
}, { "Id": "6", "Name": "Client 6", "Active":true }, { "Id": "8", "Name": "Client 8", "Active":true }, { "Id": "7", "Name": "Client 7", "Active":false }, { "Id": "9", "Name": "Client 9, "Active":true } ]
```

When the URL is mapped to RESTful service, I get no error and I don't get to see the data either. When the URL is mapped to static data 'data.json' the screen appears to be blank and when I debug the code I can see the error message 'url is undefined'. Browser is IE 11.0. Seeking your advice here.

Comment: If you're getting `url is undefined`, you probably put `data.json` in the wrong folder on the server.

Comment: data.json is places in the same folder where the html file is saved.

Comment: Are they on a server? You can't use AJAX for local file access.

Comment: The files are not on server. And i can see the functions are being called from the libraries when I debug the code.

Comment: To overcome the doubt i had, i referenced the libraries after saving them locally. However, the error is persistant.


    <script src="resources/jquery-2.1.3.min"></script>
    <script src="resources/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

Comment: You can get library files locally, but you can't use AJAX locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the below code which works.

you need to set datatype to local if you are not loading data from server.

> When the URL is mapped to static data 'data.json' the screen appears
>   to be blank and when I debug the code I can see the error message 'url
>   is undefined'.

for the above point, the json data was not proper, was missing double quotes.

As far as loading json from the server, i might need  to see the actual data returned form the server

```html
[ { "Id": "1", "Name": "Client 1", "Active":true }, { "Id": "3", "Name": "Client 3", "Active":true }, { "Id": "2", "Name": "Client 2", "Active":false }, { "Id": "5", "Name": "Client 5", "Active":false }, { "Id": "4", "Name": "Client 4", "Active":true
}, { "Id": "6", "Name": "Client 6", "Active":true }, { "Id": "8", "Name": "Client 8", "Active":true }, { "Id": "7", "Name": "Client 7", "Active":false }, { "Id": "9", "Name": "Client 9, "Active":true } ]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <title>My First Grid</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <table id="list"></table>
  <div id="pager"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

var griddata=    [ { "Id": "1", "Name": "Client 1", "Active":"true" }, { "Id": "3", "Name": "Client 3", "Active":"true" }, { "Id": "2", "Name": "Client 2", "Active":"false" }, { "Id": "5", "Name": "Client 5", "Active":"false" }, { "Id": "4", "Name": "Client 4", "Active":"true"
}, { "Id": "6", "Name": "Client 6", "Active":"true" }, { "Id": "8", "Name": "Client 8", "Active":"true" }, { "Id": "7", "Name": "Client 7", "Active":"false" }, { "Id": "9", "Name": "Client 9", "Active":"true" } ];

      $("#list").jqGrid({
   //     url: 'data.json',
        //url: 'http://localhost/api/ClientData',
data:griddata,
        datatype: "local",
        mtype: "GET",
        colNames: ["Id#", "Client Name", "Is Active"],
        colModel: [{
          name: "Id",
          sortable: true
        }, {
          name: "Name",
          sortable: true
        }, {
          name: "Active",
          align: "right",
          sortable: false
        }],
        pager: "#pager",
        rowNum: 5,
        rownumbers: true,
        rowList: [5, 10, 15],
        height: 'auto',
        width: '500',
        loadonce: true,
        caption: "Client Data"
      }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
        edit: true,
        add: true,
        del: true,
        search: true
      });
    });
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some possible reasons:

1. do NOT do cross domain access. keep your html page in the same domain with your RESTful url
2. do NOT use local file system. use a web server to serve your json file.